# Java 1.8 safepoint timeout

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection, centos

I seem to be running into a scenario where the JVM is stuck indefinitely in trying to get to a safe point after a few hours. However, if I do a jstack with -F option it seems to get out of that wait and continues with the execution.

jdk1.8.0_45/bin/jstack  -F 39924 >a.out

I am using jdk1.8.0_45 on Centos

My questions are:

i) It seems that the JVM can come out of that safepoint indefinite wait when sent an interrupt from jstack. How come it doesnt come out without jstack. Is there some jvm option I can use to avoid that indefinite wait.

ii) Can I get a more definite thread dump of the the thread that's causing the issue. The output from the safepoint log seems imprecise.

The options I am using are:.

```
-server
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=85
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30
-XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4M
-XX:+PrintGC
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1LogLevel=finest
-Xmx6000m
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=999
-XX:+SafepointTimeout
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=20000
-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics
-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1
```

The safepoint log

```
vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17771.115: G1IncCollectionPause             [     170          0              0    ]      [     0     0     0     0     8    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17771.125: RevokeBias                       [     170          1              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17771.127: RevokeBias                       [     170          1              1    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17771.131: RevokeBias                       [     170          1              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17771.955: RevokeBias                       [     169          0              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17772.160: BulkRevokeBias                   [     171          0              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17772.352: RevokeBias                       [     170          1              3    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17773.596: RevokeBias                       [     169          0              1    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

 # SafepointSynchronize::begin: Timeout detected:
 # SafepointSynchronize::begin: Timed out while spinning to reach a safepoint.
 # SafepointSynchronize::begin: Threads which did not reach the safepoint:
 # "Thread-14" #115 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f20c8029000 nid=0x9cd0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 # SafepointSynchronize::begin: (End of list)
```

After the jstack interrupt this is what I see from the safepoint log

```
vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
17779.826: G1IncCollectionPause             [     169          1              1    ]      [3315603     03315603     0     8    ]  1

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
21095.439: RevokeBias                       [     169          2             13    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
21095.439: RevokeBias                       [     169          1              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     0    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
21095.441: RevokeBias                       [     184          3              4    ]      [     0     0     3     0     1    ]  0

vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
21095.447: RevokeBias                       [     190          0              2    ]      [     0     0     4     0     2    ]  0
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code which can reproduce the problem? Also, err... Dumb question but what _is_ a safe point anyway? A link summarizing it would be helpful -- this, or a short explanation

Comment: Also, why this flurry of JVM options? Is this just for playing around or to try and solve an actual problem? If yes, what problem?

Comment: This summarizes what a safepoint is: http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html. Some of the options are for the garbage collectors, others are for debugging purposes. The  code is too complex to post  but apparently there seems something inherent in JVM where an interrupt is somehow causing the JVM to behave normally.

Comment: When you run `jstack -F`, what stack does `Thread-14` show? That might be helpful. My answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393470/what-causes-long-spin-and-sync-times-in-java and the one I link to there might give you some additional pointers.

Comment: your JVM options kinda look like being copy-pasted together without understanding them.

Comment: jstack -F for the thread didnt print out anything(empty). It seems that jstack was unable to get the stack dump for the specific thread.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are able to remedy the problem by interrupting the VM and you're on CentOS the problem reminds me of [this kernel bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64).

The thread lists the following affected versions (assuming standard kernels):

> - RHEL 6 (and CentOS 6, and SL 6): 6.0-6.5 are good. 6.6 is BAD. 6.6.z
>     is good.
> - RHEL 7 (and CentOS 7, and SL 7): 7.1 is BAD. As of yesterday.
>     there does not yet appear to be a 7.x fix.
> - RHEL 5 (and CentOS 5, and
>     SL 5): All versions are good (including 5.11).