# Why does IntStream.average() always return correct result while LongStream.average() sometimes doesn't?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
double average = LongStream
   .of(-4480186093928204294L, -1340542863544260591L, -6004296286240039273L)
   .average()
   .getAsDouble()
```

This returns `2.20723960999901594E18` but I'm expecting it to return `-3.9416750812375014E18` instead.

On the other hand, this returns a correct result (`-1.4628605853333333E9`):

```
double average = IntStream
   .of(-1282256274, -1645263673, -1461061809)
   .average()
   .getAsDouble()
```

Why does `IntStream.average()` always return a correct average value and `LongStream.average()` sometimes doesn't?

Comment: The `IntStream` behaves normally because the sum is cast to a `double`, since an `OptionalDouble` is returned.  You won't overflow/underflow it without exceeding `Double.MAX_VALUE`/`Double.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @JacobG. In `LongStream` the sum is also cast to `double`

Comment: Not explicitly though.  Notice that `double n = -6004296286240039273L;` compiles; no cast is necessary.

Comment: @JacobG I think you totally miss the point. This has nothing to do with the int to double conversion (and doubles at all). It is about choosing the right type for the accumulation of the sum value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum of the inputs exceeds the range of a `long` so the values wrap around to positive. (This is usually referred to as *negative overflow*. Usually *underflow* applies only to floating point, but it's started to come into usage to mean negative integer overflow.)

To fix, convert to double before computing the average:

```
double average = LongStream
   .of(-4480186093928204294L, -1340542863544260591L, -6004296286240039273L)
   .mapToDouble(x -> x)
   .average()
   .getAsDouble();

-3.9416750812375014E18
```

(update)

Overflow can also occur with `IntStream`, but it doesn't happen with the second example:

```
IntStream
    .of(-1282256274, -1645263673, -1461061809)
    .average()
```

The reason is that the intermediate values for the `average` operation on `IntStream` are converted to `long` variables. Even though summing these values as `int` will overflow, after conversion to `long` they won't. See the [source code for IntPipeline](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntPipeline.java#l445).

Of course, if you provide enough `int` values in an `IntStream`, they will potentially overflow the intermediate `long` variables and you'll have the same problem.

You always have to watch out for overflow when dealing with large magnitudes or large numbers of integral values. There's no escaping it.

Comment: I know about overflow. I'm more curious why IntStream.average() and LongStream.average() behave differently.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Oh. You edited the question. Maybe that's why you're being downvoted. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: I think this is rather unfortunate that I should always remember to add `mapToDouble` :(

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Just use a `DoubleStream`.

Comment: So, they sacrifice correctness in favor of performance. Handling long overflow would cost too much.

Comment: Mind the existence of [`asDoubleStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#asDoubleStream--) which can be used instead of `.mapToDouble(x -> x)`. @ZhekaKozlov: you get what you ask for. The purpose of the primitive type stream specializations is to calculate using the specified type. Even summing using `double` doesn’t warrant a *correct* result. There are cases where calculations using `long` can provide a result closer to the correct number than using `double` for the same numbers.

Comment: @Holger With your logic `IntStream` should use an `int` accumulator, but it uses `long` instead. So, I cannot fully agree with your statement.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: using a `long` instead of `int` doesn’t impose loss of precision, unlike using `double` instead of `long` would. And for most of today’s systems (if not even all of them), using `long` instead of `int` for summing up does not affect the performance.

Comment: @Holger At least `long` is slower on 32-bit Java. And sometimes it can be [slower on x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844048/why-is-long-slower-than-int-in-x64-java)

Answer (score -1):

Numbers are too big for long, we are getting overflow:

```
System.out.println(-4480186093928204294L  -1340542863544260591L -6004296286240039273L);
```

6621718829997047458